# How to escape strings before insert query?

Tags: 8, database

I've used [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to make strings safe before using Drupal.

Must I escape string before inserting it to database? If the answer is yes, then how must I do it?

I use something like this to insert into database:

```
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('mydb');
$connection = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection();
db_insert($table_name)->fields(array(
'myfield1' => 'My String',
))->execute();
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to worry about escaping. The Drupal [database abstraction layer](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/group/database/8.2.x) is taking care of query parameter escaping by turning them into placeholders and escaping the data.

Comment: ... as long as you either use one of the query builders like select, update, insert, .. and the fields() or condition() methods. If you use query() or ->where() method of query builders, make sure you use :placeholders and you are fine too.